# Facebook search form a term with geolocation

Tags: facebook, facebook-graph-api, facebook-fql

Facebook has the Keyword Insights API that solves this question, but it's not available for all developers - except for some partners and we have this example:

```
SELECT location_results FROM keyword_insights WHERE term='Obama' AND country='US'
```

From https://developers.facebook.com/docs/keyword_insights/#examples

But without have access to Keyword Insights API is it possible search for user posts that have the term "Obama" in coordinates 39.781762,-89.649854 with a radius of 50 miles?

Thanks in advance.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

**No**. It's not possible to get insights from the user posts without an access to the Keyword API.

An alternate can be to use the [Facebook Graph API Search](https://developers.facebook.com/docs/reference/api/search/). It allows you to narrow your search to a specific location and distance. For example, you can specify the latitude and longitude using the center parameter in the query:

```
https://graph.facebook.com/search?q=obama&type=posts&center=37.76,-122.427
&distance=1000&access_token=<token>
```

You can parse the result obtained from it and generate insights on your own.

Comment: Worked with "&type=post" but I can find only public posts :(